# Expand survey by its weight

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to expand a survey by it's weight by year and id so as to perform some regressions.
I am willing to the following dataframe

```
df 
id    year   weight    X       Y
 1    2011        2   54  Medium
 1    2012        1   57  Medium
 2    2011        1    8   Micro
 2    2012        2   10   Micro
 3    2011        3   10   Micro
 1    2012        1    9   Micro
```

transform it to something like this (the example is just and example to illustrate my issue, my real dataset have a lot of ids and features)

```
id    year   weight    X       Y
 1    2011        2   54  Medium
 1    2011        2   54  Medium
 1    2012        1   57  Medium
 2    2011        1    8   Micro
 2    2012        2   10   Micro
 2    2012        2   10   Micro
 3    2011        3   10   Micro
 3    2011        3   10   Micro
 3    2011        3   10   Micro
 1    2012        1    9   Micro
```

Comment: I think you are looking for over sampling

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [`pd.Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
res = df.set_index(['id', 'year', 'X', 'Y'])['weight']\
        .repeat(df['weight'])\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

   id  year   X       Y  weight
0   1  2011  54  Medium       2
1   1  2011  54  Medium       2
2   1  2012  57  Medium       1
3   2  2011   8   Micro       1
4   2  2012  10   Micro       2
5   2  2012  10   Micro       2
6   3  2011  10   Micro       3
7   3  2011  10   Micro       3
8   3  2011  10   Micro       3
9   1  2012   9   Micro       1
```